# Add Read/Write Permission to Partition

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, root, chown

How can you change add Read/Write access to a partition? It was made on Windows, in a exFAT format.

When I have it mounted on system startup, I `cd` into `/mnt/myuuid`, I got read access, but not write access unless I use sudo. However, I want to make it so I don't need sudo.

I ran:

```
sudo chown -v root:root /mnt/uuid
```

in `sudo su`, but it said:

```
chown: changing ownership of '/mnt/uuid': Operation not permitted
failed to change ownership of '/mnt/uuid' from root:root to user:user
```

How to fix?

Comment: try to add `rw` flag to `/etc/fstab`'s string

Comment: wdym? I don't have that string...